# Explantion for the ending of I am Mother

Tags: plot-explanation, i-am-mother

I apologise if the title is bland, but I didn't want to spoil anything for people who have not seen the movie yet. Spoilers ahead.

At the end of *I am Mother*, mother asks Woman "why did she not remember her parents?", and "why she had survived for so long when no one else could?". And states that "Someone must have had a use for her, until now." And thus her survival was clearly planned by Mother. This heavily implies that Woman must be one of the previous iterations of children that mother raised. I'm willing to believe that, honestly. It seems plausible that mother could have dropped Woman into the hands of survivors, who cared for her. The problem with this? How the hell did Woman know anything about the Tonight Show? She claims that she had seen it "a long time ago". Clearly, this could not be possible given the constraints that we have been presented. The only way she could have watched it is if she wasn't a previous iteration. And if she was a previous iteration that had watched it on one of the holopads, then wouldn't she remember being in the bunker with Mother?

Does anyone have an explanation for what I have mentioned? Is this a plot hole in an otherwise great movie?

Comment: The last two paragraphs of this question seem to detract from its quality to me. It’s a reasonable question about the ending, followed by two paragraphs of subjective musing. I suggest deleting the last two paragraphs and just asking about how the ending could make sense.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree with your suggestion; I have updated the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that Woman was a previous iteration, but one factor leads me to think it isn't.

The embryo Mother removes on DAY 1 after extinction event is identified as APX01.

The Daughter we see as a near adult and helping Woman, I will call APX 03, based on the identification on the test unit she used. We first see her is on DAY 13,867, almost 38 years after the extinction event.  I take it that APX03 was the third iteration since there are three embryos missing from the female storage stack.

Since the age of the character Woman is not defined, I think it is fair to say she could be older than 38, I think she looks older.  Hilary Swank is 44.  So it seems more likely that Woman was six years old when the extinction event happened.  Which would make it entirely plausible she was familiar with The Tonight Show.